# Using the ID Column to create customised ID value

Tags: 2007, designer-workflow

SharePoint 2007 Standard
SharePoint Designer 2007

I'd like to explore the possibilities around using the ID column in creating a customised ID value.  For instance, for a change log, I'd like to use CHL and then the auto generated ID value.

As we all know, using the ID column in a calculated column isn't advised.  I thought this might be doable with a workflow.  SO, I've created an additional (single line of text) column with the view of appending the ID value onto my own string.

I've run into an issue where the "set field in current item" option in SPD 2007 allows you to set a string OR the value of another column not both.  (See below)

[image: SPD2007 Set Field Action]

I'm after any ideas as to how others might have gotten around this limitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the set operation, insert a build dynamic string, I think that's what it is called in 2007, to concatenate CHL and the ID and store that in a variable. Then in your Set action, you use that workflow variable.

Comment: This worked a treat, totally forgot about this.  Thanks Eric

Comment: Anytime, glad we got it working.